# Cropped SVG with Clip-path changes Height on zooming in and out

Tags: html, css, svg

I have Successfuly Cropped a SVG with clip-path property but the problem is when Chrome Window is Zoomed in or out the SVG height changes and I wanted it to remain fix weather chrome window is zoomed or resized.

**Here is a SS taken at 100%(Default) chrome window zoom and how it should remain for diffrent zooms**
[Here is the Link please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTNGS.png)

and,

**Here is a SS of Zoomed window and the problem I am facing**
[Here is the link for Zoomed in chrome window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysg3d.png) and[Here is the link for Zoomed out chrome window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IScFZ.png)

I am also attaching the code snippet for the cropped SVG with clip-path.

```css
body {
  background: #efe944;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.liquid {
  display: block;
  width: 218px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.upper-part {
  transform: translateY(200px);
}

.lower-part {
  clip-path: polygon(0 200px, 100% 200px, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="liquid">
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 291.5 391.5">
              <title>Liquid_Bk500</title>
              <path
                class='lower-part'
                d="M290.77,20.81v350c0,11.05-64.92,20-145,20s-145-8.95-145-20v-350c0,11.05,64.92,20,145,20S290.77,31.86,290.77,20.81Z"
                style="
                  fill: red;
                  stroke: #fff;
                  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                  opacity: 0.7000000000000001;
                "
              />
              <ellipse
                class='upper-part'
                cx="145.77"
                cy="20.81"
                rx="145"
                ry="20"
                style="
                  fill: red;
                  stroke: #fff;
                  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                  opacity: 0.8;
                "
              />
            </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*NOTE:After Running snippet try to zoom in or out you will see the problem in the SVG lower part(in `<path>`).*

**I have similar Questions previously asked containg same SVG image but have diffrent issues please do not confuse yourself with those and do no close my question because of those this question is diffrent.**

Comment: Use an SVG clipPath to clip the shape rather than a CSS clip-path. Clearly CSS clipPaths have issues in Chrome whereas SVG one's don't.

Comment: @RobertLongson Remember me I am the one Who asked you the question you just refered me and made this qustion duplicate of that. This is a diffrent issue than that. this is my new account

Comment: Best not to keep creating new accounts. Clearly what you want doesn't work. I'm referring you to another answer that does.